# How do disable GitLab sign-in/login for all users while it's undergoing maintenance?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, maintenance-mode

We have an instance of GitLab running in a VM. Whenever I need to update GitLab and its Ubuntu system, I make a snapshot of the VM, perform the updates, and check if everything works fine.

Once in a while there will be problems: running out of disk space during the update, etc. If this happens, I simply restore the snapshot of the VM, and everything is just as before, and I can try again.

Unfortunately, GitLab needs a running instance to update. So, if I do a `sudo gitlab-ctl stop` before the update, the update will fail. This means that users may log in to the system while the update is in progress. Worse still, if I happen to run into problems and have to go back to the snapshot, every work done on GitLab during that time will be lost (comments on merge requests, pushes, etc.)

I use GitLab's notification messages that appear on each page of GitLab as well as in the server response from `git push` commands. However, they are widely ignored by users.

So the question is:

- What is the best strategy to update GitLab without the risk of loss of data?
- How can I prevent users from using GitLab during maintenance?

Comment: Duplicate of a question on askubuntu, which is also part of Stack Exchange: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195372/server-maintenance-disallow-ssh-and-http-for-everybody-except-myself